# Wrap part title in part's page with titleformat

Tags: spacing, parts, wrap

I am using titleformat to make some adjustments in the part's page and I want to wrap the title in half, to be centered as a text, but on the right side of the page. Any ideas?

This is my code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\huge\raggedleft }
{\thispagestyle{empty}
Part \thepart \\ \vspace{35pt}\bfseries#1}  
{0pt} 
{}
\begin{document}
\part{Introduction to Quantum Field Theory}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You want the title itself to be on two lines, if I understand well?

Comment: Yes. Itself in two line and centered (like it is in an imaginary box) but at the left side of the page.

Comment: You said at the right side in your post.

Comment: yes right. My mistake.

Comment: And `Part I` must also be centred?

Comment: Yes all together to the right

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles ,newparttoc, explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\thispagestyle{empty}\huge\bfseries\filleft }
{}%
{0pt}
{\begin{tabular}{c@{}}
\mdseries\partname~\thepart\\[35pt]#1\end{tabular}}

 \titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{160pt}{0pt }

 \begin{document}

\part{Introduction to \\Quantum Field Theory}

\end{document}
```

[image]